# vertical and horizontal border lines

Tags: html, css

How is the best way to handle the borders on `td` tags?

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/smxGH/

## code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>wee</td>
        <td>wee</td>
        <td>wee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>wee</td>
        <td>wee</td>
        <td>wee</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    margin:10px;
    border:0;
    border-spacing:0 0;
    border-collapse:separate;
}

td {
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-left:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding:4px;
    background:#dddddd;
}

tr:hover > td {
    background:#cccccc;
}
```

I need the top and bottom border to be layed over the right and left border. Now the vertical borders overlap 1px in each cell.. Is it possible to solve with CSS, or do you need `div` tags etc inside each `td` tag?

Furthermore the vertical borders need to be colapsed (1px borders) unlike the top and bottom which are separated

Comment: Do you need to use a table for this? You can find very elegant floated div solutions here at SO

Comment: If you find yourself putting a `<div>` inside a `<td>`, just **stop**, because you're not properly doing your job.  `<table>`'s are for display of tabulated data, and `<div>`'s are for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your `td` CSS-rule, and added a few exceptions to it. I hope I understood you correctly. Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

```
td {
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    background:#dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

td:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

td:first-child {
    border-left:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Another way of doing the same thing as above I found could be:

```
table {
    margin:10px;
    border:0;
    border-collapse:separate;
    /* vvv changes here vvv */
    border-spacing:1px 0;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

td {
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    background:#dddddd;
}
```